# Wordpress get posts as a function

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I'm trying to create a function to show a list of posts in my admin menu of wordpress but because I'm calling the function a few times on the same page I needed to add some extra statements but it breaks the output and I don't know why

Here is my current code that outputs the basics:

```
function test() {
    // The Query
    query_posts( array ('posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
    // The Loop
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
     ?>
    <option value="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
    <?php endwhile;
    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
    }
```

Output code:

```
<select>
<?php test(); ?>
</select>
```

Returned Output:

```
<select>
<option value="http://website/posttitle1">POST TITLE 1</option>
<option value="http://website/posttitle2">POST TITLE 2</option>
<option value="http://website/posttitle3">POST TITLE 3</option>
</select>
```

But I need to add a select option on like this:

```
function test($select) {
    // The Query
    query_posts( array ('posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
    // The Loop
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
     if ($select == the_permalink()) { $selected = " selected"; }
     ?>
    <option value="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option><?php echo "\n"; ?>
    <?php endwhile;
    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
    }
```

Output code:

```
<select>
<?php test("..GET Permalink from Database.."); ?>
</select>
```

But then this is my output:

```
<select>
http://website/posttitle1<option value="http://website/posttitle1">POST TITLE 1</option>
http://website/posttitle2<option value="http://website/posttitle2">POST TITLE 2</option>
http://website/posttitle3<option value="http://website/posttitle2">POST TITLE 3</option>
</select>
```

I dont understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the_permalink() print the value and get_permalink() returns the value.

Try this.

Change the following line

```
if($select == the_permalink()) { $selected = " selected"; }
```

to

```
if ($select == get_permalink()) { $selected = " selected"; }
```

And this line to

```
<option value="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option><?php echo "\n"; ?>
```

this

```
<option value="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></option><?php echo "\n"; ?>
```